# Копирование статей из Википедии в описания меток — это плохо

Tags: поддержка, метки, правки, описание-метки, авторские-права

Копировать текст из Википедии — плохая идея.

Во-первых, нельзя просто взять и скопировать. Необходимо **указать источник**.

Во-вторых, статьи в Википедии описывают объект, а описания метки описывают **использование метки на сайте**, кроме всего прочего.

На данный момент в метки [внесено ужасающее количество копипасты из Википедии без каких-либо ссылок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177676/vadik?tab=activity&sort=all). Мало того, что один юзер взялся без разбора заполнять описания меток, так ещё и куча пользователей безответственно подошла к утверждению описаний меток.

Модераторы, прошу принять меры. Скорее всего, все правки следует откатить.

Comment: Написал десяток орывков с первой страницы и мелкую спискостатью по C, но некоторые описания действительно не очень качественные.

Comment: @Vadik, обратите внимание на данное обсуждение.

Comment: Участник @Kuskov тоже.

Comment: Это же касается и участника @Dmi7ry.

Comment: @Nofate Вроде, обращения не работают, если юзер не участвовал в посте...

Comment: Да, [похоже на то](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work). Попробую связаться напрямую.

Comment: Меры приняты, вся копипаста прошла откат, кроме нескольких отрывков, которые были переработаны другими участниками. @Athari, спасибо за тревогу.

Comment: @Nofate Наверное, стоит ещё уведомить тех, кто утверждал правки. Иначе история повторится.

Comment: @Nofate касательно меня - если что, я перевожу описания меток с оригинального SO. Вероятно, зря я потратил на это несколько часов. Что же, спасибо, больше этим для ru.so заниматься не буду.

Comment: @Dmi7ry, касательно вас я отклонил выдержку по [tag:sfml] за это: `SFML (простая и быстрая мультимедиа библиотека) — свободная кроссплатформенная мультимедиа библиотека. Написана на C++, но доступна также для C, D, Java, Python, Ruby, OCaml, .Net, Go и др. Представляет собой современный объектно-ориентированный аналог SDL.`

Comment: Другие ваши описания меток - на месте.

Comment: @Nofate И что тут вам не понравилось?

Comment: @Dmi7ry Вероятно, то, что единственное различие со статьёй в википедии — это "и др.". Это не перевод английской метки.

Comment: @Nofate Во-первых, мой текст несколько больше, чем в вики: `SFML (простая и быстрая мультимедиа библиотека) — свободная кроссплатформенная мультимедиа библиотека. Написана на C++, но доступна также для C, D, Java, Python, Ruby, OCaml, .Net, Go и др. Представляет собой современный объектно-ориентированный аналог SDL. Может использоваться как минимальная оконная система для интерфейса с OpenGL, так и в качестве полнофункциональной мультимедийной библиотеки для создания игр или интерактивных программ.`.

Comment: @Nofate Во-вторых, вики и английская версия частично пересекаются, поэтому и была частично процитирована вики (так как, на мой взгляд, хорошо дополняет оригинал). `SFML (Simple Fast Multimedia Library) is a portable and easy to use multimedia API written in C++. You can see it as a modern, object-oriented alternative to SDL. SFML is composed of several packages to perfectly suit your needs. You can use SFML as a minimal windowing system to interface with OpenGL, or as a fully-featured multimedia library for building games or interactive programs.`

Comment: @Nofate В-третьих, что, частичная цитата вики - запрещена?

Comment: @Dmi7ry, позволю себе процитировать Athari: _"Копировать текст без ссылки на источник **запрещено лицензией** Википедии. **Юридический запрет**. В принципе нельзя так делать. И на копирование без ссылки отдельный пункт в списке запретов на содержимое в описании метки. Остальное уже нюансы и пожелания."_

Comment: Ознакомьтесь что ли с [условиями использования вики](https://wikimediafoundation.org/wiki/Terms_of_Use/ru#7._.D0.9B.D0.B8.D1.86.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B7.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D1.81.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B6.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.BE) и лицензией [Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82_%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B8_Creative_Commons_Attribution-ShareAlike_3.0_Unported).

Comment: И да, то что в английской версии SO есть косяки с лицензированием текстов не значит, что мы должны наследовать их. Это лишний повод наведаться к коллегам и починить. Совсем не трудно вбить перевод в гугл и проверить перед тем как постить. Мне вчера пришлось это проделать 40 раз.

Comment: Каюсь, похоже одобрил несколько таких описаний. А вот по поводу «описание объекта» и «описание метки» не понял. Может и есть какие-то сложные случаи, но большинство меток это название продуктов, технологий и прочего подобного, какое таким меткам описание писать? «Метка foo используется для вопросов связанных с foo»? Тут полезнее кратно описать сам продукт, дать ссылку на документацию, ещё что-то такое. По моим описанием для [nginx] и [ubuntu] замечания есть? Стоит продолжать писать такое? Там вроде тоже чуть-чуть копипасты их ru.wiki, но совсем мало.

Comment: По поводу разницы понятий "метка" и "объект" можно посмотреть описание метки [`oracle`](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/oracle/info). Это отнюдь не идеальная калька с описания на англоязычном сайте, но довольно хорошо демонстрирует разницу этих понятий из-за неоднозначности обозначения. P.S. Может стоит сформулировать правила что должно содержаться в кратком и в полном описании метки и показывать ссылку на это описание на странице редактирования?

Answer (score 1):

> Во-первых, нельзя просто взять и скопировать. Необходимо указать источник.

мне кажется, это совсем не проблема: действительно, надо всего лишь указать ссылку на источник информации в полном описании метки.

и, кстати, неплохо написать об этом в форме редактирования описания меток (если ещё не написано, что я не могу проверить в данный момент из-за (надеюсь) временного запрета внесения правок).

Comment: Краткие выдержки не предполагают ссылок. Там должна быть краткая информация о границах применения метки. Всё. / В длинную статью можно накопипастить и сослаться, но — зачем? Зайти в википедию и так каждый может, зачем нужен скопипастенный огрызок? И в статье лучше дать информацию, важную для программистов, а не какие-то общие описания. В википедии этого мало. / Скажу по секрету: копипастить без ссылки на источник, наплевав на лицензию, нельзя вообще нигде на сайте, а не только в статьях меток. Это общее правило всея Интернета, международных законов и законов вашей страны.

Comment: @Discord а нет ли у вас под рукой ссылок на хорошие, способные послужить образцом, описания меток? в которых был бы чётко прописан именно предлагаемый вами подход: «краткая информация о границах применения метки». мне кажется, ссылки на такие образцовые описания совсем не повредили бы в форме редактирования меток (которая, кстати, по моим воспоминаниям, довольно аскетична и даже способна сбить с толку: там два поля для заполнения, и какое из них для чего именно служит, я, к стыду своему, до сих пор не знаю).

Comment: Образцово-показательные статьи: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info и прочие

Comment: @Discord ого! это ж целые статьи. / мне кажется, написание таких длинных и подробных пояснений вряд ли необходимо (если вообще возможно) для бо́льшей части существующих меток.

Comment: Необходимости нет, но вы же просили лучшее. ;)

Comment: @Discord спасибо за примеры! в наибольшей степени меня интересовала реализация предлагаемого вами подхода «краткая информация о границах применения метки». прошу прощеиня, что плохо акцентировал этот момент в своём вопросе.

Comment: @Discord «Краткие выдержки не предполагают ссылок» — насколько я помню текст `CC BY-SA`, там нет оговорок про размер цитаты: надо приводить ссылку в любом случае. / поэтому мне кажется вполне разумным привести краткое описание с указанием на его источник и дополнить его (описание) «краткой информацией о границах применения метки». / надеюсь, я не сильно ошибаюсь?

Comment: 1. Как вы сошлётесь на источник, если текст без форматирования ссылок? 2. Нафиг этот мусор везде во всплывающих подсказках? 3. Если человек не способен самостоятельно написать 10 слов для краткого описания, то ему не нужно трогать вики. Вообще никогда. Хоть со ссылками, хоть без. Надо просто найти другое занятие и оставить вики тем, кто способен связать пару слов.