# Обращения к "виновникам" на мете

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, модерация, комментарии, мета

Наткнулся на старый пост [Копирование статей из Википедии в описания меток — это плохо](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/138/220571) на мете 2015го года. Нормально ли то, что модератор в комментариях обращается к участникам, к которым этот пост может относиться?

- > @Vadik, обратите внимание на данное обсуждение.
- > Участник @Kuskov тоже.
- > Это же касается и участника @Dmi7ry.

Это противоречит идее об "обсуждении действий, а не участников" или нет? Можно ли так делать не только модераторам?

Comment: в 15м году идея "обсуждения действий, а не участников" еще не практиковалась )

Comment: @Nofate, скорее об этом просто никто не думал :-)

Comment: @Grundy, да, в апреле мы только переехали с Хэшкода и жили по старым правилам.

Comment: а еще есть [вот](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/660/186999) и [вот](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1777/186999) :) @Nofate

Comment: @Nofate, Славные времена небинайсности, раздолбайства и повсеместного счастья. И сравним теперь, с бинайсом и шлю... зами к доброте.

Comment: Если бы не 15 год, там должен бы был быть Qwertiy!

Comment: Какой-то не очень дружелюбный пост. "Тыканье носом"?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Да просто спросил. Серьёзно.

Comment: Но не стоило привлекать внимание меты ради этого. То, что участников поместили на публичную доску позора "Они копипастили описания меток" это не очень справедливо, но лучше бы это решать через флаги или чат. Т.к. сейчас вы эту доску позора продублировали, и в 10 раз заметнее...

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Никакой "доски позора" я не создавал, я искренне хотел прояснить нормально ли так делать или нет. Во-первых, одним из самым первым этот пост заметил модератор, который никак не отреагировал на саму причину. Он мог бы удалить свои комментарии и последующие. Почему вы ему об этом не скажите, что это нехорошо? Во-вторых, у нас на оскорбительные флаги реагируют далеко не всегда, а чат для обсуждения этой проблемы не очень подходит по самому формату. В-третьих, может у кого-то возникнет такой же вопрос, тогда он сможет найти это обсуждение.

Comment: "Почему вы ему об этом не скажите, что это нехорошо?" - Потому что я не считаю это важным. Кроме того, потому что такое обсуждение имело бы обратный эффект: комментарии бы все равно никто не удалил, а только к пользователям привлеклось больше ненужного внимания.